# Trading automated - The machine replace the man

Tags: statistics

I learnt that Renaissance Technologies Corp. (James Simons) is mostly automatized. I mean most of the trading is automated (It's just amazing!!). How could it possible? How much work time there he has to get to the machine replaces the man in this situation?

Comment: This might be better for the quantitative finance SE.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the wikipedia page on [Algorithmic Trading.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_trading)

Virtually all institutional traders have some form of this now. There is extensive gradation ranging from the computers having full autonomy to careful supervision by experts. Sometimes things can go very wrong though. Look at what happened to [Knight Capital Group,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Capital_Group#2012_stock_trading_disruption) they lost almost half a billion dollars in an hour.